# Как сделать обработчик onChange для инпута в React таблице

Tags: javascript, reactjs, table

Всем привет! Мне необходимо сделать таблицу, в которой которой есть инпуты и написать обработчик событий для них.
Сейчас из-за того, что атрибут name инпута один для всех, данные собираются только с одного инпута и создается новое поле в объекте данных, мне надо, чтобы менялось конкретное поле в стейт переменной, как это сделать? Спасибо заранее)

У меня следующая структура данных:

```
const testData = [
            {
              id: 1,
              courier: 'TEST',
              data: [
                {
                  date: '01.10',
                  ordersName: 'Заказы',
                  orders: 23,
                  distanceName: 'Дистанция',
                  distance: 800,
                },
                {
                  date: '02.10',
                  ordersName: 'Заказы',
                  orders: 13,
                  distanceName: 'Дистанция',
                  distance: 120,
                }]
```

Разметка

```
    function Table() {
const [testDataState, setTestDataState] = useState(testData)
      const headColumns = Object.values(testData[0])[2];
      return (
        <div className='table-courier-wrapper'>
          <form>
            <table className='table_courier'>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th className='table-courier__head-fixed' rowSpan='2' colSpan='2'>
                    Курьер
                  </th>
                  {headColumns.map((el) => {
                    return (
                      <th key={el} className='table-courier__head' colSpan='2'>
                        {el.date}
                      </th>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  {headColumns.map((el) => {
                    return (
                      <>
                        <th key={el.ordersName} className='table-courier__head'>
                          {el.ordersName}
                        </th>
                        <th key={el.distanceName} className='table-courier__head'>
                          {el.distanceName}
                        </th>
                      </>
                    );
                  })}
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                {testData.map((tableData) => {
                  return (
                    <tr className='table-courier__row'>
                      <td className='table-courier__main-fixed' colSpan='2'>
                        {tableData.courier}
                      </td>
                      <ReadOnlyRow
                        tableData={tableData}
                        handleEditFormChange={handleEditFormChange}
                      />
                    </tr>
                  );
                })}
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </form>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Компонент ReadOnlyRow, в котором содержатся строки таблицы с данными:

```
function ReadOnlyRow({ tableData, handleEditFormChange }) {
  const [isClicked, setIsClicked] = useState(false);
  const handleCellClick = () => {
    setIsClicked(!isClicked);
  };
  return (
    <>
      {tableData.data.map((el) => {
        return (
          <>
            <td className='table-courier__main'>{el.orders}</td>
            {isClicked ? (
              <td className='table-courier__main'>
                <input
                  className='table-courier__input'
                  type='text'
                  name='distance'
                  defaultValue={el.distance}
                  onChange = {handleEditFormChange}
                />
              </td>
            ) : (
              <td className='table-courier__main' onClick={handleCellClick}>
                {el.distance}
              </td>
            )}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};
```

Функция обработчик инпута:

```
  const handleEditFormChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setTestDataState({
      ...testDataState,
      [name]: value,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я все правильно поняла, и нужно доработать, чтобы в state обновлялся нужный элемент массива, то я бы делала как-то так

```
const { data } = testData
const [testDataState, setTestDataState] = useState(data)

const handleEditFormChange = ({value, key}) => {
    let newTestDataState= [...testDataState]
    newTestDataState[key] = value
    setTestDataState(newTestDataState)
}
    
<ReadOnlyRow
    key={indexRow}
    tableData={tableData}
    handleEditFormChange={({value}) => handleEditFormChange({value, key: indexRow})}
/>
```

где `indexRow` это индекс элемента строки, который нужно добавить в map.
Так же в самом компоненте ReadOnlyRow в обработчик допилить `handleCellClick`, чтобы было

```
handleCellClick (event) {
event.stopPropagation()
// и тут поднимать handleCellClickProps наверх с нужным value
}
```